# Old sci-fi story, humans meet alien spaceship that burns planets while searching for meaning of life

Tags: story-identification, spaceship

Can you please help me find this old sci-fi story. It went something like that:

In the future, humans discover through telescope that somebody is traveling from planet to planet and sets them on fire. Humans send a spaceship to investigate. The human spaceship meets an alien spaceship which does the planet burning. They talk to the aliens. The aliens claim to be searching for the meaning of life (or something like that). Then, the human spaceship returns to Earth. But on return, they discover that the Earth has changed a lot and nobody on Earth cares about space travel anymore.

I think I read it somewhere in the 1980s so it must have been written before that. That's all I remember about the story. Can somebody recognize it?

Comment: I read it somewhere in the 1980s, I think. So it must have been written before that.

Comment: Was it a novel, or a short story?